# How to associate a contact with an object

Tags: windows-phone-7

I've a model *Person* which should be created from contacts. If the user opens the view of a person there should be a button which opens this contact in the address book from where I got the contact information.

Is it possible to save a pointer to the contact in my model *Person*?

Comment: You can bind your view model to your view. But post some code.

Comment: using bindings is not my problem. this works fine. I don't know which information I have to save in the object to create a link to the entry in the windows phone address book.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to have a look at this article:
http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/How-to-choose-a-Contact-and-get-Contact-details-in-a-WP7-app

The autor explains how you can get contact data from the phone address book!

If you want to open the contact details page as from the address book, I'm afraid this is not possible.

Comment: Thank you. I already found this article. It describes how I can get the information. But is it also possible to get an "identifier" of this special contact to be able to open the contact in the address book anytime I list the person in my app?

Comment: It seems I missunderstood what you want to do. Do you want to open the contact details as from the adress book?

Comment: Yes, I want to open the contact details of a person who is in the address book of the windows phone.

Comment: Too bad. I think so too :-(. If you edit your posting and add this information I'll accept your answer.